# Exception raised during rendering after adding bottomAppBar

Tags: android, material-design

Design view isn't rendering new edits to ui and It says this.. **`Exception raised during rendering: java.lang.ClassCastException`**, However the App works fine with no problems in UI.
This problem only occurs after adding this code:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/actionBar_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topBar_view">

        <!-- Other components and views -->


        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:buttonGravity="bottom"
            app:fabAlignmentMode="end" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/setWallpaper"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_camera_24dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Stack Trace Details:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@5ea77ada
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor308.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.callMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:108)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:143)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder.java)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.access$400(PropertyValuesHolder.java:38)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$FloatPropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue(PropertyValuesHolder.java:1387)
    at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:990)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.animateBasedOnTime(ValueAnimator.java:1339)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1471)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.pulseAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1490)
    at android.animation.AnimatorSet.pulseFrame(AnimatorSet.java:1163)
    at android.animation.AnimatorSet.handleAnimationEvents(AnimatorSet.java:1146)
    at android.animation.AnimatorSet.doAnimationFrame(AnimatorSet.java:1046)
    at android.animation.AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(AnimationHandler.java:146)
    at android.animation.AnimationHandler.access$100(AnimationHandler.java:37)
    at android.animation.AnimationHandler$1.doFrame(AnimationHandler.java:54)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:947)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
    at android.view.Choreographer_Delegate.doFrame(Choreographer_Delegate.java:66)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.renderAndBuildResult(RenderSessionImpl.java:563)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:425)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.BridgeRenderSession.render(BridgeRenderSession.java:120)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:151)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:133)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$null$8(RenderTask.java:755)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

***build.gradle:***

*implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09'*

Comment: post the full stacktrace

Comment: I edited the post